# Question about existence of a minimal resolution in the proof of Theorem 19.6 in Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let A be a local ring and M an $A$-module which has a finite free resolution $$0\rightarrow F_{1}\rightarrow F_{0}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0.$$ In this situation, does a minimal resolution $$0\rightarrow L_{1}\rightarrow L_{0}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$ of M always exist?

In the proof of Theorem 19.6 in Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory", I got stucked at this point. Why one can say M has a minimal resolution with a length less than two?

Comment: I suppose that it is called minimal for a reason. Anyway, if we have a finite free resolution when build a minimal one the last kernel is free by [Schanuel's lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_lemma).

Comment: Oh, thanks! I forgot that every projective module over a local ring is free.